# Having problems using PhongMaterial in THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I try to instance a PhongMaterial on the wings of my plane, one works fine yet the other seems to shade always in the same way regardless of the sun's position, only changing in reflection intensity.

These are the materials in question

```
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
      shininess: 30,
      color:0xA9A9A9,
      side: THREE.BackSide,
      //emissive: 0xA0A0A0,
      //emissiveIntensity:0.8
    }),
    new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors,
      side: THREE.FrontSide,
      color: 0x00ffff,
      shininess: 30,
      emissive: 0x00ffff,
      emissiveIntensity: 0.9
    }),
```

[With a sun on each side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9R4p.png)

As you can see the Right wing lights up properly yet the Left doesn't.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYhI9.png)

Even when the sun is almost on top of the left wing it still doesn't reflect properly. The right wing is still working as expected

Both wings are using BackSide, have the same material and are built the same way
I'm using THREE.Geometry for this, every triangle is hand made. I've made sure the math is working fine.
I already have called .computeVertexNormals().

I don't even know why this could be happening, if someone could help I'd be thankful.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please create a [`Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) using [snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to show exactly what's happening? Maybe just recreate the wings, rather than the whole project.

Comment: Are you scaling the wing geometry by -1 to mirror it? If so, it might be a normals issue. Since you're using Geometry, you might need to also perform .computeFaceNormals()

Comment: I've finally found what was doing the bug. The bottom and upper faces of the wing were too close together. Don't know why the right wing didn't have any problems but they are both fixed now. Thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found what was doing the bug. The bottom and upper faces of the wing were too close together. Don't know why the right wing didn't have any problems but they are both fixed now. Thanks for the help anyways